# Session files CHmod

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, backup, sessions

My Magento Store is hosted on a Directadmin enabled server,

But all the Session files stored in /var/sessions/ are created with CHmod 600 and user Apache,

The Session folder him self is Owned by the directadmin user, and CHmod 777

The problem is that the backup function in Directadmin can't read the files because the files are chmod 600 and owned by Apache ( User and group )

Is there a way that magento create the session files with CHmod 655 or simmilar so directadmin can create a succesfuly backup of the files ?

Comment: why not use database saved sessions?

Comment: Preformance Wise i have seen that file-based sessions are much faster, but thats a solution... first trying to use the file-based solution.

Comment: I see. I agree with @JesseC - there should be no reason to backup the session data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento does not control what mode the session files get stored in, you will need to consult your server provider for shared hosting or if you control the server yourself, you can look into using various methods such as an ACL for the directadmin to read the files if your server supports it.

However, normally you would exclude var/session from backups. There's no benefit to backing up those files.

Comment: Thanks, I have Seen that this is not normal,
With Symlinking i have moved the session and Cache folder outside the directory with is not backuped, with the [following manual](http://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=281)